# Prove that $A\setminus B$ is non-countable where $A$ is a non-countable set and $B\subseteq A$ is a countable set.

Tags: cardinals

**Problem:**
Let $A$ be a non-countable set and let $B\subseteq A$ be a countable set. Prove that $A\setminus B$ is non-countable.

Where, $(X \text{ is non-countable})\;\iff (|X|>|\mathbb{N}|)$.

---

Of course, a way to prove this would be by finding a function $f:A\to A\setminus B$ that's injective to show that $|A|\leq |A\setminus B|$ thus finishing the proof. I can´t seem to be able to find shuch a function.

My *guess* would be that a function like that should exist due to the following special case:

> $$\big|\mathbb{R}\setminus\big(\;]-\infty,-\pi/2]\cup [\pi/2,\infty[\;\big)\big|=\big|(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\big|=\big|\mathbb{R}\big|$$
> Thanks to the existence of the function $\tan:(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to\mathbb{R}$ which is bijective.

How could I find an appropriate function to prove **Problem**?

---

*Please help adding or removing tags if necessary. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Do you already know the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are both numerable (I think it's more common to say "denumerable" or "countable") then $X\cup Y$ is also numerable? What happens if you apply that fact with $X=A\setminus B$ and $Y=A\cap B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $B$ is countable, there exists an injection $f : B \rightarrow \mathbb N$

Suppose $A \setminus B$ is countable. Then there exists an injection
$g : A \setminus B \rightarrow \mathbb N $.

Now let $h : A \rightarrow \mathbb N$ be defined by

$$
h(x) =
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
2f(x) \quad &\text{if} \quad x \in B \\
2g(x) + 1 \quad &\text{if} \quad x \in A \setminus B
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$h : A \rightarrow \mathbb N$ is an injection so $A$ is countable, which is a contradiction.